# Why is the engagedSessions metric incompatible with the pageTitle dimension in path exploration report?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

The [[GA4] Data compatibility - Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11608978?hl=en) documentation suggests checking [GA4 Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/#pageTitle) to verify whether certain dimensions and metrics are compatible. According to it, `pageTitle` dimension and `engagedSessions` metric should be compatible:

[image]

However it is not the case in path exploration report:

[image]

The [[GA4] Get started with Explorations - Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7579450?sjid=7338214913686591852-AP#limits-of-analysis&zippy=%2Cin-this-article) documentation doesn't explain anything about this. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What type of report are you trying to create? I was able to use the Freeform report and view Engaged sessions by Page Title...

Comment: hmm, mine is path exploration

Comment: For that report, I bet engaged sessions isnt a valid metric. You will probably need to switch to views to continue to leverage that report.

Comment: yeah, I just lookup [\[GA4\] Path exploration - Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9317498?hl=en "[GA4] Path exploration - Analytics Help") and it says that it only supports event counts and total users. Still, why is engaged sessions not a valid metric?

Comment: My guess is an engaged sessions is looking at a users entire progress through your site. And technically with this report you can implicitly see people who have seen more than 2 pages. So I'm a way you can see engaged sessions...kind of.

Comment: thanks. If you make that an answer I'll accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of report that you are trying to create, certain metrics might not be available. For Path Exploration, engaged sessions isn't a viable metric.

Comment: do you think it's a good idea to add the info from our conversation to the answer as well?